# jQuery bound functions called for every time AJAX page loads

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I hope this is not too difficult to figure out and I'm just being an idiot.  I've got a section of my web app loading via AJAX with some navigation within the `<div>` element.  However, every time the user reloads the page it increases the number of times all my bound JQuery functions are run!  This is an issue both for performance and because some of my functions use a .toggle() method so it only works if the function is called an odd number of times.

I don't understand why setting the click event multiple times would cause this effect.  Maybe it has something to do with how often the buttons themselves are rendered but I don't understand that since the contents of the `<div>` are being overwritten each time.

I don't know if this would matter but I'm using the Laravel 5.2 framework for this app.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```js
/**
* FUNCTION FOR REVEALING AND LOADING OR HIDING THE FORM FOR ASSIGNING PREDEFINED
* SOURCES TO SURVEY PRODUCTS.
*/
function myDelSource()
{
  console.log('myDelSource called to assign function to #delSource buttons');
  $("div.myoutput").on("click",".delSource",function(){
    var source_id = this.id;
    console.log('ID passed to DelYes button: ' + source_id);
    $("#delYes").val(source_id);
  });
}
function inlineAJAX ()
{
  console.log('inline AJAX called');
  $("body").on('click','.inlineAJAX',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('InlineAJAX triggered');
    var tag=$(this).attr('tag');
    var url=$(this).attr('url');
    var em = $(tag).find('div');
    var emTag= '#' + em.attr('id');
    if (em.html().length<1)
    {
      loadComponent(url,emTag);
    }
    $(tag).toggle();
  });

}
function delYes(url)
{
  $("#delYes").attr('url',url);
  console.log("delYes function called, the following url was passed: " + url);

  $("body").on("click","#delYes",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('delYes action triggered');
    var sps_id=$("#delYes").val();
    deleteSPS(sps_id);
    myurl=$("#delYes").attr('url');
    loadComponent(myurl,"#surveys");
  });
}
function b100()
{
  $("body").on('click',".100",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var mytag="#"+this.val();
    $(mytag).val(100);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(init);
  function init()
  {
    myDelSource();
    inlineAJAX();
    b100();
    delYes("/survey/{{$survey->id}}/products");
  }
</script>
```

Comment: easy. you're using event delegation AND binding the events every time the content is loaded. do one or the other, not both.

Comment: @KevinB Thanks for the suggestion.  I realize this may come off as an idiotic request and if I wasn't on such  tight deadline I'd do this myself but could you perhaps show how I am doubling down on delegation and binding?  I'm not quite seeing it at the moment.

Comment: use the non-event delegation form of .on, or do whatever would be required to have the code only run once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is based on a sort of defensive coding approach.  If your user is really reloading the page, the problem absolutely should not occur, as you suggest.  But let's assume that somehow redundant event handlers are getting set up due to circumstances beyond your control.

In your situation one practical way to approach it would seem to be to have your handler setup functions remove old handlers before setting up the new ones.  In jQuery you can do this with code like

```
$(whatever).off('click','.inlineAJAX');
```

or similar.  The documentation page http://api.jquery.com/off/ discusses various options that remove handlers more or less selectively.  You might even choose to do just:

```
$(whatever).off('click');
```

Code of this sort could appear at the beginning of each of your setup functions.

Comment: can chain them with the `on()` as well ... `$(whatever).off('click','.inlineAJAX').on('click','.inlineAJAX'....`

Comment: Thanks! I continued to look around and just implemented that method.  It works perfectly.  I'm still curious what is going on as it may have larger implications.

For reference, the whole page is not reloaded but rather the innerHTML of a <div> element.  I can reset the "counter" of how many times the functions run by reloading the entire page.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue with some code I wrote, that I couldn't find any rational reason for there to be two bindings, but yet, certain buttons would clearly activate twice, no matter what.  So I ended up adding this before my binding, which is similar to Cris P. answer:

```
jQuery( "#buttonId" ).unbind( "click" );
```

Just read a bit about `off()` vs. `unbind()` and it appears that `unbind()` is deprecated.  Looks like I have some code to go update!

Comment: Yeah, I started looking into `unbind()` and scrolled to that part of the jQuery docs.  It seemed to me that the browser was "remembering" the previously rendered buttons that were overwritten when the html in the div was refreshed.  I added a `$("div.my_section").empty()` command to try and wipe out the any phantom html but to no avail.  The `.off()` method is the only thing that has worked.